# How to lock controls in WPF Visual Studio designer to avoid accidental changes?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

In Winforms there was an option to lock the controls in Visual Studio that are selected to avoid accidental move or resize, I was not able to find a similar feature with WPF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the XAML Designer in Visual Studio, in the Design Menu, there is a Lock submenu. In that submenu you Lock the currently selected control, Lock All controls, or Unlock All controls.

However, the lock is a bit different than it was in Winforms. The WPF control will be completely locked, meaning you can't even select it until you Unlock All.