# How can I edit a locked file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a xaml file that I try to edit, but after I make the change and I run the code I see a little sign of lock in the name of the file. The change is not made,
how can I change it?

[image]

```
<Menu Grid.ColumnSpan="6" IsEnabled="False">
        <MenuItem Header="_FILE" FontSize="20" Height="25" Width="310" Padding="30,0,0,0">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open_file..." Click="Open_file_Click" FontSize="20"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open_folder.." Click="Open_folder_Click" FontSize="20"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_open_with_server" Click="open_with_server" FontSize="20"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_open_with_server" Click="open_with_server" FontSize="20"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_add_song_to_server" Click="add_song_to_server" FontSize="20" 
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="CloseApp_click" FontSize="25"></MenuItem>
            <ListBox Name="lbFiles" />
        </MenuItem>
```

This is the code I want to edit.

Comment: You may have it locked (on accident), please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336027/how-to-lock-controls-in-wpf-visual-studio-designer-to-avoid-accidental-changes#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=When%20using%20the%20XAML%20Designer,controls%2C%20or%20Unlock%20All%20controls.)  and or what pete mentions below. I've only seen this when debugging and or I have manually locked it so I don't accidentally make changes I didn't intend on doing.

Comment: Is the projecct compiling or is it already running?Normally, when your app has run successfully, you can edit xaml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the program still running? When I start to debug, I get a lock symbol on the file (very briefly) while the project is building. Depending on your settings/version, the lock may also be applied while the code is running.

Comment: Hey @pete, this isn't really an answer, more a comment. Nice Avatar though ;)

Answer (score 0):

i deleted and download visual studio 2019 and its finaly work
this is extremely solution but it work.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.